# Form with rows, trying to get the values as a array object

Tags: antd

I am trying to create row based form with ant design form component. It will look like the screenshot.

Getting the submitted value as a single object as shown in the screenshot(console).

[image]

Is there any simple way/solution to archive it by an array object with each row values like below.

```
[{
  receiver_name0: "Jaison 1",
  receiver_email0: "jaison1@gmail.com",
  receiver_phone0: "05555555"
},{
  receiver_name1: "Jaison 2",
  receiver_email1: "jaison2@gmail.com",
  receiver_phone1: "06666666"
}]
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using `getFieldDecorator` provided by antd Form, the first argument the `getFieldDecorator` is a string that is a path to where the value should be set. It works pretty much like lodash `_.set()`.

Check out this: https://github.com/react-component/form/pull/48

To set form values in an array you can try something like this from the example in the PR:

```js
{getFieldDecorator('row[0].receiverName', {})(<input/>)}
{getFieldDecorator('row[1].receiverName', {})(<input/>)}
```

etc.

Comment: Thanks for your replay and sorry for the delay. I have tried your approach but no luck, It would be nice if you can make a fiddle for me. https://codepen.io/jaison-james/full/BEKBNv

Comment: @Jaison What is the issue you are experiencing? Your codepen mostly works for me, except strangely nothing is logged to the codepen console, only to the browser console.

Comment: As mentioned in the OP, I would like to get the submitted value as an array object instead of an object.

Comment: @Jaison so you just want the top level level object submitted to be an array rather than an object with a `names` property that is an array?

Comment: Yes, not only array, it should be an array object as I mentioned in the example. like [{
  name: "Jaison 1"
},{
  name: "Jaison 2"
}]